# JavaFX 8, how to get center location of Scrollpane's Viewport

Tags: javafx-8

[image: Viewport Center]

**The Problem**

I'm trying to figure out a way to get at which point *in the content node* the scroll pane's viewport is centered on.

To elaborate on the picture above, the big rectangle is the content (let's say a large image), and the small rectangle is the portion that is shown by the scroll pane. I'm trying to find x and y which would be coordinates from the top left of the content.

**What I've Tried**

My first thought was to use the `getViewportBounds()` method of the scroll pane and use its `minX` and `maxX` properties to determine the center x point:

```
Bounds b = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
double centerX = (b.getMinX() + b.getMaxX()) / 2;
double centerY = (b.getMinY() + b.getMaxY()) / 2;
```

However, this doesn't work because these numbers are *negative* and don't seem to accurately describe the **x** and **y** I'm looking for anyways.

My next thought was to use the scroll pane's `hValue` and `vValue` to get the top left corner of the viewport relative to the content:

```
Bounds b = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
double centerX = scrollPane.getHvalue() + b.getWidth() / 2;
double centerY = scrollPane.getVvalue() + b.getHeight() / 2;
```

This didn't work either though as the `hValue` and `vValue` seem to be way too large (when scrolled in only a few pixels, I'm getting numbers like 1600).

**My Questions**

I seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the viewport works with a scroll pane.

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone explain where these numbers come from? How do I find **x** and **y** like in the picture above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `(x, y)` be the be coordinates of the top, left point shown in the viewport. You can write this as

```
((contentWidth - viewportWidth) * hValueRel, (contentHeight - viewportHeight) * vValueRel)

vValueRel = vValue / vMax
hValueRel = hValue / hMax
```

This means assuming `hmin` and `vmin` remain `0` you can keep a circle in the center of like this:

```
// update circle position to be centered in the viewport
private void update() {
    Bounds viewportBounds = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
    Bounds contentBounds = content.getBoundsInLocal();

    double hRel = scrollPane.getHvalue() / scrollPane.getHmax();
    double vRel = scrollPane.getVvalue() / scrollPane.getVmax();

    double x = Math.max(0, (contentBounds.getWidth() - viewportBounds.getWidth()) * hRel) + viewportBounds.getWidth() / 2;
    double y = Math.max(0, (contentBounds.getHeight() - viewportBounds.getHeight()) * vRel) + viewportBounds.getHeight() / 2;

    Point2D localCoordinates = content.parentToLocal(x, y);
    circle.setCenterX(localCoordinates.getX());
    circle.setCenterY(localCoordinates.getY());
}

private Circle circle;
private Pane content;
private ScrollPane scrollPane;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // create ui
    circle = new Circle(10);
    content = new Pane(circle);
    content.setPrefSize(4000, 4000);
    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(content);
    Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 400, 400);

    // add listener to properties that may change
    InvalidationListener l = o -> update();
    content.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(l);
    scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(l);
    scrollPane.hvalueProperty().addListener(l);
    scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(l);
    scrollPane.hmaxProperty().addListener(l);
    scrollPane.vmaxProperty().addListener(l);
    scrollPane.hminProperty().addListener(l);
    scrollPane.vminProperty().addListener(l);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```